# OpenCL 1.2 Mem Object flags

Tags: memory, opencl

So reading through the OpenCL 1.2 reference pages, I noticed a difference in clCreateBuffer.

There are three new cl_mem_flags that pretain to the host usage: CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, CL_MEM_HOST_WRITE_ONLY, and CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS. I was just a bit confused how these differ from the cl_mem_flags from earlier versions? Wouldn't CL_MEM_READ_ONLY AND CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY accomplish the same thing?

Also, do these flags affect how you call functions such as clEnqueueRead/Write/Map/UnmapBuffer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These new flags are basically the "host-counterparts" of the original flags.

For example, consider the `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY` flag:

> This flag specifies that the memory object is a read-only memory object **when used inside a kernel**.

In contrast to that, for `CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY`:

> This flag specifies that the **host** will only read the memory object

(from the [clCreateBuffer documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html), emphasis by me)

They thus allow a more fine-grained specification of what you will do with the memory:

```
Host read, Kernel write
Host write, Kernel write
Host read+write, Kernel read
....
```

This enables the OpenCL implementation to perform optimizations under the hood, quoting from the above mentioned documentation:

> This flag specifies that the host will only write to the memory object (using OpenCL APIs that enqueue a write or a map for write). This can be used to optimize write access from the host (e.g. enable write combined allocations for memory objects for devices that communicate with the host over a system bus such as PCIe).

---

Of course this will affect how the buffer may be used. For example, when you create a host-read-only buffer with `CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY`, then an attempt to write to this buffer with `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` will fail - again, refering to the [documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueWriteBuffer.html):

> **Errors**
>
> **`clEnqueueWriteBuffer`** returns `CL_SUCCESS` if the function is executed successfully. Otherwise, it returns one of the following errors:
>
> ...
>
> `CL_INVALID_OPERATION` if `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` is called on buffer which has been created with `CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY`

Comment: thank you, that definitely makes it more clear the differences